# how can I do for Aten operator torch.mv when convert pytprch to onnx

Tags: pytorch, onnx

## background

`torch.mv` operator is include in my pytorch model, so when I convert that model to onnx, console print

```
RuntimeError: Exporting the operator mv to ONNX opset version 11 is not supported. Please feel free to request support or submit a pull request on Pytorch Github
```

So I have to do something for the `torch.mv` operator. However I can not understandand the description in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html?highlight=onnx#module-torch.onnx) of `torch.onnx`.

## question

- I can not confirm whether the `torch.mv` is an aten operator, because I can not find the declaration about the `mv` function in `torch/csrc/autograd/generated/VariableType.h`, however [somebody says](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27723) it is. Below, it is the content in `VariableType.h`.

```
#pragma once
// @generated from tools/autograd/templates/VariableType.h
#include <ATen/ATen.h>
#include <c10/util/intrusive_ptr.h>
#include <torch/csrc/WindowsTorchApiMacro.h>
#include <cstdint> // for size_t
#include <functional> // for function
#include <memory> // for unique_ptr
#include <string>
#include <vector>
namespace at {
  struct Quantizer;
};
namespace torch { namespace autograd {
using Variable = at::Tensor;
using at::Context;
using at::Device;
using at::Dimname;
using at::DimnameList;
using at::Generator;
using at::IntArrayRef;
using at::MemoryFormat;
using at::QScheme;
using at::Scalar;
using at::ScalarType;
using at::Storage;
using at::Tensor;
using at::TensorList;
using at::TensorOptions;
using at::Quantizer;
// This is temporary typedef to enable Quantizer in aten native function API
// we'll remove them when we are actually exposing Quantizer class
// to frontend
using ConstQuantizerPtr = const c10::intrusive_ptr<Quantizer>&;
using c10::optional;
namespace VariableType {
  TORCH_API std::vector<at::DeprecatedTypeProperties*> allCUDATypes();
  TORCH_API std::vector<at::DeprecatedTypeProperties*> allCPUTypes();
  at::Tensor & unpack(Tensor & t, const char * name, int pos);
  const at::Tensor & unpack(const Tensor & t, const char * name, int pos);
  at::Tensor unpack_opt(const Tensor & t, const char * name, int pos);
  std::vector<at::Tensor> unpack(at::TensorList tl, const char *name, int pos);
};
}} // namespace torch::autograd
```

- In the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/onnx.html#aten-operators), it take `elu` for illustration, but `elu` is standardized in ONNX and `mv` is not, so how can I do for export the model to onnx including `torch.mv`
  ps: I can not find the contents `virtual Tensor elu(const Tensor & input, Scalar alpha, bool inplace) const override;` in `VariableType.h` as that docs says, why? :(

## code for reproduce error

```
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch


class custom_net(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self,):
        super(custom_net, self).__init__()
        self.sigmoid = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, martix, vector):
        martix = self.sigmoid(martix)
        vector = self.sigmoid(vector)
        outputs = torch.mv(martix, vector)
        return outputs


if __name__ == "__main__":

    net = custom_net()
    net = net.eval().cuda()
    martix = Variable(torch.randn(2, 3)).type(torch.FloatTensor)
    vector = Variable(torch.randn(3)).type(torch.FloatTensor)

    martix = martix.cuda()
    vector = vector.cuda()

    input_name = ["martix", "vector"]
    output_name = ["output"]

    torch.onnx.export(net, (martix, vector), "net.onnx", input_names=input_name, output_names=output_name,
                      opset_version=11)
    print("done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

torch.mv is an ATen op and it is not currently supported by the ONNX exporter. I'll send a PR to support this op. Meanwhile, if you can modify your model code, you should be able to replace torch.mv with torch.matmul and export the model to ONNX.